# Joystick & USB Devices (General)

Tags: linux, usb, game-controller

I have an HID compliant USB device that purports that it will be detected as a joystick in Linux.  Whenever I connect it to my computer, there is no /dev/js0 /dev/js1 or any js at all under /dev/input.

However, it seems that /dev/input/event2 can "read" the device's data stream.

The device has the following properties:

```
1 Axis
6 Buttons
```

Why is it that it isn't being detected as a joystick (js) ? I am using Linux CentOS 5.5.

EDIT: More specifically, if you can explain/tutorial me what /dev/input/eventN (n is an integer) is... that would be helpful!

Comment: I have no idea, but I'm just curious what device is 6 buttons but only one axis.

Comment: A binocular (that acts like a joystick and a peripheral video feed)

Comment: I must not be understanding you correctly because I am thinking of the things you put up to your eyes to see things far away and that makes no sense to me, aha!

Comment: @Shinrai - That's correct.  Instead of being able to see far away, you get to see a video output inside the binoculars.

Comment: Fascinating.  I hope somebody can help you out!

Comment: I know this is a too old article, but I found this link: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gamepad  It seems /dev/input/event* refers to new input system in linux.